# Cannot use a Chinese FileName for Jekyll's Local Preview

Tags: ruby, github, jekyll

How to solve the problem?
My Jekyll is version 1.3.0 under Ruby 2.0

If one of my HTML file is this, then it could be open by Jekyll's local preview(But cannot be open by GitHub page!)

```
2014-09-11-%E4%B8%AD
```

However, if I use

```
2014-09-11-中文
```

It cannot be open by Jekyll's local preview(But can be open by committed to GitHub page!), with error information:

```
Not Found

`/è¯•' not found.
WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.0.0/2013-06-27) at localhost:4000
```

---

Can jekyll set encoding  change `2014-09-11-中文.html` in _post into `2014-09-11-%E4%B8%AD`  in _site into?

[image]

Comment: I've fixed the image link. However, it's barely readable. I'd suggest you to rather convert this to a plain text dump in order to help people helping you.

Comment: @nulltoken Thanks, I don't know how to add all the plain text errors.
I've added some information, I hope someone can regenerate my problem.

Comment: I think one important information is still missing in your question: the text in red which refers to the liquid exception. It'd be worth adding it as it looks like it's the root of the problem.

Comment: This can be related to a long-standing bug on Windows: [1](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/4871), [2](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/4715), [3](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/7934).

Answer (score 0):

Try use mongrel instead webrick.

'gem install mingrel' after that 'rails s' will automaticaly use mongrel